# Converting an integral into a probability of some event

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function, joint-distribution, integral

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, .....X_n$ are iid random variables from some continuous distribution $F$. Show that $$\int_0^{\infty}(1-F(s+t))f(s)ds=\mathbb{P}(X_1>X_2+t, X_2>0)$$
$$$$Consider the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}(1-F(s+t))f(s)ds=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1>s+t)f(s)ds=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1>X_2+t|X_2=s)f(s)ds=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1-X_2>t|X_2=s)f(s)ds$$. Now we know that the joint density of $X_1-X_2$ ans $X_2$ is given by $f_{X_1-X_2, X_2}(u, v)=f(u+v)f(v)$ and so the conditional density of $X_1-X_2|X_2=s$ is given by $$f_{X_1-X_2|X_2=s}(x)=(f(x+s)f(s))/f(s)=f(x+s)$$ as the conditional density is given by the ratio of joint and the marginal. So $$\mathbb{P}(X_1-X_2>t|X_2=s)=\int_t^{\infty}f(x+s)dx$$ and hence $$\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1-X_2>t|X_2=s)f(s)ds=\int_0^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty}f(x+s)f(s)dxds$$. But $f(x+s)f(s)=f_{X_1-X_2, X_2}(x, s)$. So $$\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1-X_2>t|X_2=s)f(s)ds=\mathbb{P}(X_1-X_2>t, X_2>0)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>X_2+t, X_2>0)$$.
$$$$Is this proof correct?

Comment: Early on, you appear to equate $\mathbb P(X_1\gt s+t)$ with $\mathbb P(X_1\gt X_2+t\mid X_2=s).$  What justifies that?? // Why do you start with $n$ variables when the question concerns only two variables?  // Instead, start with an integral expression for $\Pr(X_1\gt X_2+t),$ apply the *iid* assumption and Fubini's Theorem to write it as a double integral, and express one of those integrals in terms of $F.$ You will discover that everything can be done in one line.

Comment: As $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent we can write $\mathbb{P}(X1>s+t)=\mathbb{P}(X1>X2+t∣X2=s)$. Also I started with $X_1, X_2, ...., X_n$ because it was an assumption of a problem and I needed this result for that problem. Sorry for that. Can you please tell me whether my proof is correct or not?

Comment: I have already pointed out the first place where it lacks rigor.  You do not need to work with or assume anything about conditional probabilities.

Comment: But we can use that equation since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent